# XMLHTTPRequest not working on server on localhost

Tags: node.js, server, xmlhttprequest, localhost

I'm developing a `node.js` RESTful server for home use on a RPI with Raspbian, and for testing, I've created a **test HTML page** that makes various `XMLHttpRequest`s to it.

When developing I'm using a test `nodemon` server on my dev machine (a desktop machine, not the RPI), running on `localhost:4000`, and the **test HTML page** points to it. 
Whenever I'm ready to commit the changes, I push them to the server (the RPI), even the test page. It should connect to the server on localhost.

Something bizzare happens whenever I'm **testing the page on the server**: `localhost` is not recognized in the `XMLHttpRequest.open` method, but if I put the **address of the server machine in the network** (not 127.0.0.1, but 192.168.1.X for example), it works.

The Command `netstat -vltn` shows that the node server is listening on port `4000`, I've enabled CORS, I've already tried to write `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, and I've even modified the app.listen function to listen to `0.0.0.0`, like this:

```
app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', function () {
     console.log('RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
});
```

but still, **every request from the test page hosted on the server, to localhost:4000 doesn't work**.

My problem here is that, if I need to push the test page on the server, I need to manually change the IP address for the `XMLHttpRequest` each time, instead of just keeping localhost. Is there a way to enable the use of localhost?

**EDIT**: I'm adding some client code to flesh out the problem.

**testpage.html** (the one that should work both on the dev machine and the RPI)

```
<html>
   <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendData() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        };

        xhttp.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log('error', e);
        };

        xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:4000/auth/loginTest", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        //I've omitted the part where I'm prepping a json with username/password data
        xhttp.send(jsonString);
    }
 </script>
</head>  <!--I'm skipping the rest of the code as there's only a div that 
catches the json info sent by the server -->
```

**server.js** (the one that gets started on the RPI with `node server.js`)

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
var auth = require(/*path to Auth middleware*/);

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }));

app.options('*', cors());
app.use(cors());

app.use('/auth', auth);

process
  .on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    console.error(reason, 'Unhandled Rejection at Promise', p);
  })
  .on('uncaughtException', err => {
    console.error(err, 'Uncaught Exception thrown');
    process.exit(1);
  });

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. I forgot to post the solution.

My approach will never work, because when the test page is loaded, it will try to execute a script on `http://localhost:4000`, which is fine if the page is loaded from the machine where the server is listening, but obviously won't work if it's on another machine (hence the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error).
If I load this page from the server machine it will try to execute the script on my machine, which is an invalid request.
So I've solved it by simply substitute `http://localhost:4000` in the request with the actual IP of the machine, e.g `http://Write.Real.Address.Here:4000`.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this code:

```
app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', function () {
  console.log('RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
});
```

to this:

```
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
});
```

This will allow your app to listen on both IPv4 and IPv6. It is possible that `localhost` is resolving to the IPv6 address and your code is only listening on the IPv4 address. I know that a MAC uses IPv6 for `localhost`.

The other thing to try is stop using the word `localhost` on the client and use `127.0.0.1` and see if that makes any difference.

**UPDATE:**

Below is my server code that I generated from yours and it seems to work:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

function sendPage(req, res, next) {
  console.log('sending page');
  res.send(`<html>
<head>
  <script>
  function sendData() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      }
    };

    xhttp.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log('error', e);
    };

    xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:4000/auth/loginTest", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    //I've omitted the part where I'm prepping a json with username/password data
    xhttp.send('{"user":"dog","pw":"woof"}');
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="sendData()">
<h1>Test page</h1>
<div id="demo"></div>
<hr/>
</body>
</html>`);
}

function auth() {
  console.log('auth called');
  var router = express.Router();

  router.post('/loginTest', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('auth was called');
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({error: false, data:'hi'});
  });

  return router;
}

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }));
app.options('*', cors());
app.use(cors());
app.get('/', sendPage);
app.use('/auth', auth());

process
  .on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    console.error(reason, 'Unhandled Rejection at Promise', p);
  })
  .on('uncaughtException', err => {
    console.error(err, 'Uncaught Exception thrown');
    process.exit(1);
  });

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
});
```

> If this doesn't come close to matching your code let me know where I got it wrong.

Comment: Both solution didn't work. [Here's the error](https://imgur.com/a/JUY594p)

Comment: Can you add more of your client code?? What are your browser limitations? IE11?

Comment: I've added some client code as example. I'm currently testing `testpage.html` with the latest Opera stable, but the server will be reached with a React Native app.

Comment: I've just seen your updated code, actually my testpage and server.js files are on different locations (the page isn't generated by the server). I'd like to keep it that way if possible.

Comment: My code is an example. I set it up that way to get it to work on my machine. But the functionality works. Break my code up into two or more parts and place them where needed.